# Php script queries error

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley, image-uploading

I'm trying to test an android application that uploads on a server a photo and some text.
i prepared a PHP script that is probabily crashing while performing queries.

this is the script

```
<?php 
$user_name = "Root";
$user_pass = "";
$host_name = "192.168.1.228";
$db_name = "testupload";

$con = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name,$user_pass, $db_name);

if($con){
$image = isset($_POST["image"]) ?$_POST["image"] : "";
$text = isset($_POST["text"]) ?$_POST["text"] :"";
$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ?$_POST["name"] :"";
$upload_path = "uploads/$name.jpg";

if(mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO notifiche (zona) VALUES ('$name')") &&  
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO notifiche (Problem) VALUES ('$text')")){

    file_put_contents($upload_path,base64_decode($image));
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image Uploaded Successfully'));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Image Upload Failed'));
}
}
else{
 echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Connection Failed'));
} 

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

when trying to upload from my application, the Logged message is

```
02-06 01:14:58.311 13014-13014/disco.unimib.it.polapp D/ciao: {"response":"Image Upload Failed"}
```

that should appear only when the queries fail, but i can't get why it's happening

this is the code of the activity that is sending the picture and the text

```
public class NotifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Bitmap image;

String mCurrentPhotoPath;

File photoFile=null;

Uri photoUri;

Intent TakePictureIntent;

ImageView photoSaved;

Bitmap rotatedimg;

private String uploadUrl="http://192.168.1.228/PolApp/testupload.php";

String zona;

EditText problema;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    zona=bundle.getString("zona");


    final Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(R.string.problem);

    final Button buttonsend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsend);
    final Button buttonimage=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonphoto);
    photoSaved=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoSaved);
    problema=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.problemdescr);


    buttonimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TakePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (TakePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(NotifyActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NotifyActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                } else {
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NotifyActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                        TakePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                        startActivityForResult(TakePictureIntent, 50);
                    }

                }


            }
        }
    });

    buttonsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uploadImage();
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.notify),R.string.notificationsent,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    image= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    ExifInterface ei= null;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation=ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
    switch(orientation) {

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotatedimg = rotateImage(image, 90);
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotatedimg = rotateImage(image, 180);
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotatedimg = rotateImage(image, 270);
            break;

        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
        default:
            rotatedimg = image;
    }
    if(rotatedimg!=null){
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.notify),R.string.photosaved,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        photoSaved.setImageBitmap(rotatedimg);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    Log.d("ciao", String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String [] permissions,int [] grantResults){
    if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        try{
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NotifyActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
            TakePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(TakePictureIntent, 50);
        }
    }else{
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
}

public String imgToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte [] img=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

private void uploadImage(){
    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(NotifyActivity.this);
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uploadUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ciao",response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        String rsp=jsonObject.getString("response");
                        Log.d("ciao",rsp);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
            params.put("image",imgToString(rotatedimg));
            params.put("text",problema.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("name",zona);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.